# Understanding and using ffmpeg settings

Tags: ffmpeg

Where is the best documentation of ffmpeg and libavcodec?

It appears that ffmpeg supports many undocumented options that it is very hard to find a good reference.

Comment: what is not on [ffmpeg.org/documentation.html](http://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html) can be found in ... [the source](http://svn.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg/trunk/ffmpeg.c?view=markup) ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- ffmpeg -formats
- ffmpeg -help
- ffmpeg.org/documentation.html and the
- source code as last resort.

Unfortunately, this is not easy to figure out.

Comment: There should be a SE site for FFmpeg. Please [follow](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40292) and verify your email to cast you vote!

Answer (score 6):

One of the things that can be quite useful:

```
ffmpeg -formats
```

lists all the codecs and containers that can be used...I haven't found any other good place where these can be found, probably because they depend on what libraries your ffmpeg copy was built with.  This page (http://ffmpeg.mplayerhq.hu/general.html) has some of them, but don't tell you what to enter at the command line.

Also, howto-pages.org has a decent tutorial here: http://howto-pages.org/ffmpeg/

Answer (score 1):

`ffmpeg --help`

`ffmpeg -formats`

`ffmpeg -codecs`

`ffmpeg -`

If you use Linux, try
`man ffmpeg`

`ffmpeg -decoders`

`ffmpeg -encoders`

`ffmpeg -protocols`

`ffmpeg -filters`

And of course, if you want to do something and you can't figure it out, google is your friend. The results in the FFmpeg mailing lists are generally useful, as are results that link to stackoverflow and stackexchange. Even Yahoo Answers has occasionally given me an answer. FFmpeg documentation is also really nice.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/index.html for the libav code and api documentation.